# Validated PHP and HTML document, yet displays blank

Tags: php, html, database, forms, html-table

I made this form which is connected to other PHP files, all of them work like they are supposed to except for this form.

I validated the file which is called **addproducts.php** and no errors were found except for that I should use CSS for `cellpadding` & `cellspacing`.
The form is based upon another form I earlier created which also had the same error regarding `cellpadding` & `spacing`, although that form works just fine.
But this new form displays nothing, the page is just blank. [New form](https://gyazo.com/605134f4a6ec0e9a00d66851d94bf09b)

It should be looking like this (my first form) [result I aim for](https://gyazo.com/584eaf8ae3b307b75a05ab5c4f43fd7b)
(I apologize for the Swedish comments in the code.)

I sincerely appreciate any kind of help in this matter.

```
<?php

include_once "../db_connect.php";
include_once "html_headers.php";
error_reporting(0);
session_start();


$logged_in = (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '');

    if($logged_in) {
        if(isset($_SESSION['access']) && $_SESSION['access'] == 'admin') {
            echo rapport_header();
            echo  "<div class=adminheader><h2>Lägg till produkt</h2><a href='../index.php'>Förstasidan</a></div>";
        }
    }


    if(isset($_POST['spara'])){


        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $produktnummer = $_POST['produktnummer'];
        $produktnamn = $_POST['produktnamn'];
        $beskrivning = $_POST['beskrivning'];   
        $pris = $_POST['pris']; 
        $produktbild = $_POST['produktbild'];   
        $lagersaldo = $_POST['lagersaldo']; 
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $isonoffer = $_POST['isonoffer'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO produkter (id,produktnummer,produktnamn,beskrivning,pris,produktbild,lagersaldo,type,isonoffer) VALUES ('$id','$produktnummer','$produktnamn','$beskrivning','$pris','$produktbild','$lagersaldo','$type','$isonoffer')";

        if($mysqli = connect_db()) {

        $mysqli->query($sql);
        print_r($mysqli->error);
        }


        echo "Produkten är nu inlagd i databasen<br />";
        echo "<a href='products.php'>Tillbaka till listningssidan</a>";
    }


        ?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Lägg till en produkt</title>     
    </head>
    <body>


        <form action="addproducts.php" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">

                <tr><td>id</td><td><input type="number" name="id"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>produktnummer</td><td><input type="text" name="produktnummer"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>produktnamn</td><td><input type="text" name="produktnamn"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>beskrivning</td><td><input type="text" name="beskrivning"  /></td></tr>


                <tr><td>pris</td><td><input type="text" name="pris"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>produktbild</td><td><input type="text" name="produktbild"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>lagersaldo</td><td><input type="number" name="lagersaldo"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>type</td><td><input type="text" name="type"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>isonoffer</td><td><input type="text" name="isonoffer"  /></td></tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="spara" value="Spara" />
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `connect_db()` function???

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);` then you will actually see what errors you have

Comment: The code that you have posted is named as insert_person.php?

Comment: Just check your Web server error log or turn on error reporting to see the problem.

Comment: check server log, or if dont, than copy db_connect.php code in this file, and comment top include_once "../db_connect.php";...

Comment: @Divyesh Savaliya Its named as addproducts.php

Comment: I removed  (Resolved)  from the title in an edit. If you have an answer, post it or delete the question. Or accept one that did solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your Web server error log or turn on error reporting to see the problem.

I assume, the problem is in your `include_once`. You should use absolute paths.

Change:

```
include_once "../db_connect.php";
include_once "html_headers.php";
```

To:

```
include_once __DIR__ . "/../db_connect.php";
include_once __DIR__ . "/html_headers.php";
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything!

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Let OP check that. I used to have similar problems before + I don't see any problems in the rest of his code.

Comment: `__DIR__` just resolves to the real path of the current directory. It just changes anything if you have overwritten the `include_path` directive to not include the current directory. Otherwise, it will behave exactly as the relative path. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I know how does it work. I just suggest you to search for "php include relative path" on SO and see a lot of questions (with examples) where relative path doesn't work, but absolute works. Without overwritting directives

Comment: @akasummer Thank you guys and everyone else for your help, I checked the error logs and have now fixed all the issues. It is now working perfectly!

Comment: @GoodguyGreg May I ask what was the problem?